# how to open file on click node in wpf treeview

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a treeview which is populated from a xml file using data binding.
next thing i want to know is,how to open an txt file while on clicking on the node of the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to load the text file each time you change the select as well?   heres an idea call the event SelectedItemChanged and then use

Using System.IO;

at the top.  then create a textreader as following

```
    private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TextReader TR = new StreamReader(@"file location...");
        string contents = TR.ReadToEnd();
        TR.Close();
        //Add code to do what ever you want to to the contents of the file...
    }
```